# Android - App crash after add Firebase database Android Studio

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio

I am new at android studio.I want to save user information to database after the user register on my apps.User can registered correctly. But when i want to add the code that save the user to database it cause a problem. When i want to run it to my device the app get force close. But if i delete the code that related with save user to database it can run again. Anyone can help me about this ?

register activity

```
package com.example.ilham.dompettebal;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.service.autofill.UserData;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class register extends AppCompatActivity {
    private EditText Inputemail,Inputusername,Inputpassword;
    private TextView signin;
    private Button buttonRegister;
    private FirebaseAuth auth;
    private DatabaseReference users;
    String userId;
//    private ProgressBar progressBar;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

        auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        userId = auth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        users = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("users").child(userId);
        buttonRegister = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonRegister);
        Inputemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        Inputpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        Inputusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        signin = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.signin) ;


        signin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                startActivity(new Intent(register.this, login.class));
            }
        });




        buttonRegister.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                String email = Inputemail.getText().toString().trim();
                String password = Inputpassword.getText().toString().trim();
                String username = Inputusername.getText().toString().trim();

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(email)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (TextUtils.isEmpty(password)) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

                if (password.length() < 6) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Password too short, enter minimum 6 characters!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    return;
                }

//                progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                //create user
                auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                        .addOnCompleteListener(register.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                                Toast.makeText(register.this, "createUserWithEmail:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
//                                progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                // If sign in fails, display a message to the user. If sign in succeeds
                                // the auth state listener will be notified and logic to handle the
                                // signed in user can be handled in the listener.
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Toast.makeText(register.this, "Authentication failed." + task.getException(),
                                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    SavedUser();
                                    startActivity(new Intent(register.this, MainActivity.class));
                                    finish();
                                }
                            }
                        });

            }
        });
    }

    private void SavedUser()
    {


        Inputemail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
        Inputpassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
        Inputusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.username);
        String email = Inputemail.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = Inputpassword.getText().toString().trim();
        String username = Inputusername.getText().toString().trim();
        HashMap userData = new HashMap();
        userData.put("username",username);
        userData.put("email",email);
        users.updateChildren(userData).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful())
                {
                    Toast.makeText(register.this, "User Created" + task.getException(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }
        });

    }

}
```

app build gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.ilham.dompettebal"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'


    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.1'
}
```

logcat

```
  --------- beginning of crash
2018-12-08 17:32:04.680 5405-28014/? V/FA-SVC: Scheduling upload with DelayedRunnable
2018-12-08 17:32:04.680 5405-28014/? V/FA-SVC: Scheduling upload with GcmTaskService
2018-12-08 17:32:04.680 5405-28014/? V/FA-SVC: Scheduling task with Gcm. time: 6553
2018-12-08 17:32:04.689 5405-28014/? V/FA-SVC: Background event processing time, ms: 20
2018-12-08 17:32:06.138 28480-28605/? V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
2018-12-08 17:32:11.239 5405-28014/? V/FA-SVC: Cancelling job. JobID: 812057698
2018-12-08 17:32:11.251 5405-28014/? V/FA-SVC: Starting upload from DelayedRunnable
2018-12-08 17:32:11.266 5405-28014/? D/FA-SVC: Uploading events. Elapsed time since last upload attempt (ms): 10023
2018-12-08 17:32:11.271 5405-28014/? V/FA-SVC: Fetching remote configuration: com.example.ilham.dompettebal
2018-12-08 17:32:11.271 5405-28014/? V/FA-SVC: Not stopping services. fetch, network, upload: true, false, false
2018-12-08 17:32:11.340 5405-28014/? V/FA-SVC: onConfigFetched. Response size: 0
2018-12-08 17:32:11.345 5405-28014/? V/FA-SVC: Successfully fetched config. Got network response. code, size: 304, 0
2018-12-08 17:32:11.357 5405-28014/? D/FA-SVC: Updated lifetime engagement user property with value. Value: 3726
2018-12-08 17:32:11.370 5405-28014/? V/FA-SVC: Saving bundle, size: 472
2018-12-08 17:32:11.372 5405-28014/? D/FA-SVC: Uploading events. Elapsed time since last upload attempt (ms): 10120
2018-12-08 17:32:11.376 5405-28014/? V/FA-SVC: Uploading data. app, uncompressed size, data: com.example.ilham.dompettebal, 601, 
    batch {
      bundle {
        protocol_version: 1
        platform: android
        gmp_version: 12780
        uploading_gmp_version: 14799
        config_version: 1544238577803732
        gmp_app_id: 1:239987278985:android:fb89b133b1f5d35b
        app_id: com.example.ilham.dompettebal
        app_version: 1.0
        app_version_major: 1
        firebase_instance_id: eTilxcjKV-M
        dev_cert_hash: 2862194538385679336
        app_store: manual_install
        upload_timestamp_millis: 1544265131349
        start_timestamp_millis: 1544265120649
        end_timestamp_millis: 1544265124629
        app_instance_id: 9dc9a14314926e5d2fac2ad1bc2f0292
        resettable_device_id: 0dccc0aa-8c2d-43ee-b733-bcc037de7f18
        limited_ad_tracking: false
        os_version: 7.0
        device_model: Redmi Note 4
        user_default_language: en-us
        time_zone_offset_minutes: 420
        bundle_sequential_index: 1
        service_upload: true
        user_property {
          set_timestamp_millis: 1544265120649
          name: first_open_time(_fot)
          int_value: 1544266800000
        }
        user_property {
          set_timestamp_millis: 1544265120649
          name: first_open_after_install(_fi)
          int_value: 1
        }
        user_property {
          set_timestamp_millis: 1544265131354
          name: lifetime_user_engagement(_lte)
          int_value: 3726
        }
        event {
          name: first_open(_f)
          timestamp_millis: 1544265120649
          previous_timestamp_millis: 0
          param {
            name: firebase_conversion(_c)
            int_value: 1
          }
          param {
            name: firebase_event_origin(_o)
            string_value: auto
          }
          param {
            name: _r
            int_value: 1
          }
          param {
            name: previous_first_open_count(_pfo)
            int_value: 11
          }
          param {
            name: system_app(_sys)
            int_value: 0
          }
          param {
            name: update_with_analytics(_uwa)
            int_value: 0
          }
          param {
            name: system_app_update(_sysu)
            int_value: 0
          }
        }
        event {
          name: user_engagement(_e)
          timestamp_millis: 1544265120649
          previous_timestamp_millis: 0
          param {
            name: firebase_event_origin(_o)
            string_value: auto
          }
          param {
            name: engagement_time_msec(_et)
            int_value: 1
          }
        }
        event {
          name: screen_view(_vs)
          timestamp_millis: 1544265120984
          previous_timestamp_millis: 0
          param {
            name: firebase_event_origin(_o)
            string_value: auto
          }
          param {
            name: firebase_screen_class(_sc)
            string_value: login
          }
          param {
            name: firebase_screen_id(_si)
            int_value: -1815647252065091777
          }
        }
        event {
          name: user_engagement(_e)
          timestamp_millis: 1544265124629
          previous_timestamp_millis: 1544265120649
          param {
            name: firebase_event_origin(_o)
            string_value: auto
          }
          param {
            name: engagement_time_msec(_et)
            int_value: 3725
          }
          param {
            name: firebase_screen_class(_sc)
            string_value: login
          }
          param {
            name: firebase_screen_id(_si)
            int_value: -1815647252065091777
          }
        }
      }
    }
2018-12-08 17:32:11.376 5405-28014/? V/FA-SVC: Not stopping services. fetch, network, upload: true, true, false
2018-12-08 17:32:11.380 5405-28112/? V/FA-SVC: Uploading data. size: 484
2018-12-08 17:32:11.389 5405-28014/? V/FA-SVC: Not stopping services. fetch, network, upload: false, true, false
2018-12-08 17:32:11.438 5405-28014/? V/FA-SVC: Upload scheduled in approximately ms: 3599989
2018-12-08 17:32:11.441 5405-28014/? V/FA-SVC: Cancelling job. JobID: 812057698
2018-12-08 17:32:11.449 5405-28014/? V/FA-SVC: Scheduling upload with GcmTaskService
2018-12-08 17:32:11.449 5405-28014/? V/FA-SVC: Scheduling task with Gcm. time: 3599989
2018-12-08 17:32:11.456 5405-28014/? V/FA-SVC: Successful upload. Got network response. code, size: 204, 0
2018-12-08 17:32:11.474 5405-28014/? V/FA-SVC: Nothing to upload or uploading impossible
2018-12-08 17:32:11.476 5405-28014/? V/FA-SVC: Cancelling job. JobID: 812057698
2018-12-08 17:32:11.481 5405-28014/? V/FA-SVC: Stopping uploading service(s)
2018-12-08 17:32:17.009 28777-28777/? V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
2018-12-08 17:32:17.302 28777-28799/? V/FA: Collection enabled
2018-12-08 17:32:17.303 28777-28799/? V/FA: App package, google app id: com.shopee.id, 1:808332928752:android:71c351ab322a4a71
2018-12-08 17:32:17.303 28777-28799/? I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 12780
2018-12-08 17:32:17.303 28777-28799/? I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
2018-12-08 17:32:17.304 28777-28799/? I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.shopee.id
2018-12-08 17:32:17.304 28777-28799/? D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
2018-12-08 17:32:17.317 28777-28799/? V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2018-12-08 17:32:17.338 28777-28799/? V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2018-12-08 17:32:17.339 28777-28799/? D/FA: Connected to remote service
2018-12-08 17:32:17.340 28777-28799/? V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
2018-12-08 17:32:22.367 28777-28799/? V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
2018-12-08 17:32:47.169 28859-28859/? I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 11200
2018-12-08 17:32:47.169 28859-28859/? I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
2018-12-08 17:32:47.180 28859-28859/? V/FA: Collection enabled
2018-12-08 17:32:47.180 28859-28859/? V/FA: App package, google app id: com.google.android.apps.fireball, 1:81793200174:android:a3cee0fee63b6b7f
2018-12-08 17:32:47.181 28859-28859/? I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
      adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.google.android.apps.fireball
2018-12-08 17:32:47.181 28859-28859/? D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
2018-12-08 17:32:47.186 28859-28859/? V/FA: Cancelling job. JobID: -1358375162
2018-12-08 17:32:47.187 28859-28859/? V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
2018-12-08 17:32:47.194 28859-28882/? V/FA: Using measurement service
2018-12-08 17:32:47.195 28859-28882/? V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2018-12-08 17:32:47.205 28859-28882/? V/FA: Using measurement service
2018-12-08 17:32:47.206 28859-28882/? V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2018-12-08 17:32:47.370 28859-28882/? D/FA: Connected to remote service
2018-12-08 17:32:47.370 28859-28882/? V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 2
2018-12-08 17:32:52.402 28859-28882/? V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

Comment: Can you please share the logcat? Its hard to locate crash issues without logcat.

Comment: how to share the logcat ? i dont know how to use it..i am sorry im new on this..  is it verbose,debug,info,warn,eror,or assert ?

Comment: You select the verbose and just copy the messages printed in your logcat when the app gets crashed. Then paste the log messages here in your question.

Comment: i already add it from beginning of crash right ?

Comment: umm ... yes, this is from logcat. However, this does not show any error. I would like to suggest again to filter the "Error" instead of Verbose and put the log here again.

Comment: i think its about the base64 based on userid?

Comment: Make sure you took the logcat log beginning with  FATAL EXCEPTION: